# Homotopy groups of a wedge sum

Tags: algebraic-topology, homotopy-theory

Let $X_\alpha$ be connected CW-complexes. Then from Hatcher's book,

$$\pi_{n}(\prod_{\alpha} X_{\alpha})=\prod_{\alpha}\pi_{n}(X_{\alpha}).$$

Is it true in general that

$$\pi_{n}(\bigvee_{\alpha} X_{\alpha})=\prod_{\alpha}\pi_{n}(X_{\alpha})?$$

Answer (score 17, accepted):

No. In general, homotopy groups behave nicely under homotopy pull-backs (e.g., fibrations and products), but not homotopy push-outs (e.g., cofibrations and wedges). Homology is the opposite.

For a specific example, consider the case of the fundamental group. The Seifert-Van Kampen theorem implies that $\pi_1(A\vee B)$ is isomorphic to the free product $\pi_1(A)*\pi_1(B)$, not the product.

Answer (score 22):

No.  In fact, the homotopy groups of the wedge sum are often vastly more complicated.

For example, consider $S^1\vee S^2$.  Its universal cover looks like a line with an $S^2$ wedged at every integer point.  In particular, $\pi_2$ of the universal cover is infinitely generated (one map for each of the countably many spheres), despite the fact that $\pi_2(S^1) = 0$ and $\pi_2(S^2) = \mathbb{Z}$.

Another example may be found in Bott and Tu's book "Differential forms in algebraic topology" near page 264.

There, they compute some of the homotopy groups of $S^2\vee S^2$.  In particular, $\pi_4$, $\pi_5$, and $\pi_6$ are are infinite, even after tensoring with $\mathbb{Q}$.  But for $S^2$, only $\pi_2$ and $\pi_3$ are infinite.

Comment: Dear Professor, does it hold $$\pi_{n}(\bigvee_{\alpha} S^k_{\alpha})=\prod_{\alpha}\pi_{n}(S^k_{\alpha})?$$

Comment: Look at my answer. Hilton's Theorem precisely describes the homotopy type of a wedge of spheres. Consider to look at some examples of Hilton's Theorem to get an answer to your question.

Comment: For wedges of spheres you obtain $\pi_m(S^{r_1} \vee \cdots \vee S^{r_k})=\bigoplus_{i=1}^\infty \pi_m(S^{r_i})$ (for a certain choice of $r_i$ for $i>k$). This result due to Hilton was generalized by Milnor to suspensions of arbritary CW complexes. Hope this helps.

Comment: I can intuitively understand the reason why there are a countably infinite generators of the second homotopy group of the covering space, but can you please explain how does one prove this formally ? Also, how does the $\pi_2$ groups of the universal cover relate to that of the base space ? Thanks

Comment: I would compute $H_2$ of the universal cover using some kind of inductive Mayer-Vietories (or cellular homology).  Then I would use the Hurewicz theorem, which, in this case, tells us that the natural map $\pi_2\rightarrow H_2$ is an isomorphism to conclude what I wanted about $\pi_2$.   For your second question, if $X\rightarrow Y$ is a cover, then $\pi_k(X) =\pi_k(Y)$ for all $k\geq 2$.

Answer (score 4):

No, this follows for example from [Hilton's Theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hilton's_theorem)